# When should you let SurfaceView be drawn by UI-thread?

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-custom-view

I'm reading up on `SurfaceView` and how to use it, and I've come across some information that states that a `SurfaceView` has `View#willNotDraw()` set to false by default, and that it's up to you to call `SurfaceView#onDraw()`. I also read that RomainGuy said that this is done by default because it is more efficient. My question now is, when should you handle calling `SurfaceView#onDraw()` in a separate thread, and when should you just set `View#willNotDraw()` to `true`, and just call `SurfaceView#invalidate()`. Is there a difference between the two, and does one improve performance more than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setWillNotDraw(boolean)

I'm not sure where you got your information, but at least the javadoc says that most users will set this to `false` to get Android to send it `onDraw` events itself. As for your question about when you should do this, I would say it comes down to why you're using a `SurfaceView`.

If your view is displaying something dynamic (e.g. for a game or something that has a tight event loop), you'll want to be controlling exactly when updates happen, especially if you'll have the information to use one of the more detailed forms of `invalidate` to save redrawing the entire `View`. You won't want Android to call `invalidate` for you, and that's why the flag is there.

If, on the other hand, you are simply drawing something static, it makes sense to let Android's UI stack control the invalidations.

By the way, `invalidate` only posts a request to re-draw the `View`, so be aware of this if you intend to use the event-loop style (`onDraw` will be called sometime *after* you call it).

**Edit:** some clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Using SurfaceView.onDraw() and SurfaceView.invalidate() will make SurfaceView behave like a normal View and you will pay for the extra overhead associated with SurfaceView. If you want to draw from the UI thread, use a regular View instead. It's easier and cheaper.